# Oracle Discoverer Page Items - Multiple Selection

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

This should be a quick yes or no question:

In Oracle BI Discoverer, is there a way to select multiple page items from a crosstab/pivot report. I have a crosstab that has a field as a page items with about 9 options. It allows me to select one or all, but I cant find a way for multiples.

I've tried to Google this, but have found little documentation on it.

Answer (score 0):

**Discoverer does not have the "select multiple values" for a page item**

Unfortunately, no, there is no functionality with respect to selecting multiple values for a specific page item.  Below, I display the `Folder Name` page item for a worksheet based on the metadata end user layer business area. 
[image]

This functionality just does not exists.

Probably the best way to address this is to create a condition with the `in` operator and set the value to a parameter which is enabled for multiple values like this:

[image]

This is how this parameter works when a worksheet is refreshed:
[image]

Discoverer is old (but still reliable), and back in its day, was a good work horse for transactional reporting. Perhaps you can take this approach.